# Necessary conditions for a function to be represented as symmetric tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, symmetric-functions

Let $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ be any function of 2 arguments. Suppose also that the following equation holds $$f(y,x)+f(x,y)=g(x) h(y) +g(y)h(x) \quad \forall x, y$$ for arbitrary $h(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$. Which kind of function should $f$ be in order for $h$ and $g$ to exist?

Comment: Where does $f$ live?

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Just a hint to get started: you can forget about $f(x,y)$ and work with $s(x,y)=f(x,y)+f(y,x)$. Since there is no topology here, the domain $\mathbb{R}$ could be any set. Look first at the finite set case, say of cardinality $n$. In this situation you are asking for the conditions which characterize real quadratic forms in $n$ variables which are products of two real linear forms. Only when the finite set situation is solved should you consider infinite domains like $\mathbb{R}$.